# Can't check if $_POST variable has left empty

Tags: php, post

I need to validate a form therefore I am writing a php class that does just that. I need to check if a `$_POST` variable has been set or not in order to determine whether display an error message. So I have implemented two methods which don't seem to work as I expect, because even if I leave my form blank, it is processed as if data has been filled in, and I just don't understand.

```
private function isSubmitted($field) {
    if (!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private function hasContent($field) {
    if (!empty($_POST[$field])) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see much wrong with the code you posted, perhaps it'll be useful to look at how you're calling those methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Even when a field is left empty, it is submitted with `""` (an empty string) as its content. Therefore, `array_key_exists` will return `true`.
2. `if not empty return false` is the opposite logic of what you're trying to do.
3. Abbreviating your boolean returns to `return array_key_exists($field, $_POST);` should be considered saner, at the very least more concise.

Answer (score 2):

```
private function hasContent($field) {
    if (!empty($_POST[$field])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I think you should do a minor change.you should also check whether the existed array have value or is it empty.

Comment: more succinctly: return !empty($_POST[$field]);

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try something like this

```
private function isSubmitted($field) {
    return isset($_POST[$field]);
}

private function hasContent($field) {
    return !empty($_POST[$field]);
}
```